# How to control the visibility of a child component from the parent using a prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I'm trying to control the visibility of a child component from the parent using a prop.

My child component has a `visible` prop. To avoid mutating the `visible` prop I assigned it to a local `isVisible` ref, and I'm using that to conditionally show and hide a form.

But when I try to hide the form using a button with `@click="isVisible = false"` nothing happens, and I get a console error saying `Set operation on key "visible" failed: target is readonly`.

It's also confusing why the error messsage is referring to the `visible` prop because I am using the local `isVisible` variable instead.

This is the `ChildForm.vue` (child component):

```html
<template>
  <q-form v-if="isVisible">
    <q-input v-model="modelValue" />
    <q-btn label="Hide The Form" @click="isVisible = false" />
  </q-form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, toRef } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({
  visible: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
});
const isVisible = toRef(props, 'visible');
const modelValue = ref('');
</script>
```

This is the `ParentPage.vue` (parent component):

```html
<template>
  <child-form :visible="showForm" />
  <q-btn label="Show the Form" @click="showForm = true" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import ChildForm from 'src/components/ChildForm.vue';
const showForm = ref(false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toRef()` retains the reactive connection to the original source, so modifying `isVisible` effectively modifies the original prop, which is supposed to be readonly, leading to the warning you observed.

But I think you're actually trying to keep the child's `visible` prop in sync with the parent's `showForm` prop, such that updates in the child are automatically reflected in the parent. [`v-model`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#multiple-v-model-bindings) is the tool for that problem.

In the parent, bind `showForm` to `v-model:visible`:

```html
<child-form v-model:visible="showForm">
```

In the child, emit an `update:visible` event with the desired value whenever you want to update the parent:

```html
<template>
  <q-form v-if="visible">
    <q-input v-model="modelValue" />                  
    <q-btn label="Hide The Form" @click="$emit('update:visible', false)" />
  </q-form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  visible: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
})
const modelValue = ref('')
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-parent-prop-with-vmodel?file=src/components/ChildForm.vue)